# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError in administration with DEBUG=False

Tags: django, debugging, administration

I have a little wierd problem with Django administration. With DEBUG=True in settings.py, everything works fine. But when I change it to DEBUG=False, I can't get to page editation of item. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 136, in get_response
    response = response.render()

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py, line 104, in render
    self._set_content(self.rendered_content)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py, line 81, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 192, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 155, in render
    return self.render_template(self.template, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 137, in render_template
    output = template.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 192, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 192, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 281, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 281, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 837, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 880, in render
    return _render_value_in_context(output, context)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 858, in _render_value_in_context
    value = force_unicode(value)

  File /home/yetty/projects/Tchorici/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py, line 93, in force_unicode
    raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)

DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.forms.forms.BoundField object at 0x327bd90> (<class 'django.forms.forms.BoundField'>)
```

I have no idea, why I get it just with DEBUG=False.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have it ;)

In admin.py I have own form for MultipleChoiceField:

```
people = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    Person.objects.all(),
    widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Účastníci", False, attrs={'rows': '10'})
)

class Meta:
    model = Event
```

Even if I had

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

on the beginning of the file, "Účastníci" made troubles. When I changed it to "Ucastnici", everything works fine.

Comment: I would say encoding web pages is one thing and another thing is database encoding. Check collation and charset of your database

Comment: You're using Django which means you're still using a Python version before 3.0, which in turn means you need to [mark Unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type). Use `u"Účastníci"` instead of `"Účastníci"` and it should work.

Comment: I checked collations - thats all right. Unicode mark doesn't work. I repeat - everything is only with DEBUG=False, with DEBUG=True it works fine.

Comment: Same problem, but with users screen. HOw can I change i18n settings for auth classes? I'm still figuring it out

Answer (score -1):

I found experimentally that the error is `debug_toolbar`. With `DEBUG=True debug_toolbar` disabled